# parse html tags, based on a class and href tag using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse HTML with BeautifulSoup.

The content I want is like this:

```
<a class="yil-biz-ttl" id="yil_biz_ttl-2" href="http://some-web-url/" title="some title">Title</a>
```

i tried and got the following error:

```
maxx = soup.findAll("href", {"class: "yil-biz-ttl"})
------------------------------------------------------------
   File "<ipython console>", line 1
     maxx = soup.findAll("href", {"class: "yil-biz-ttl"})
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what i want is the string : `http://some-web-url/`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'yil-biz-ttl'})[0]['href']
```

To find all such links:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'yil-biz-ttl'}):
    try:
        print link['href']
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: what if there were more than 10 such links, your fetches only the first right?

Comment: I've modified my answer to show how you can find all such links in the page.

Comment: There are could be `<a/>` elements without `href` attribute such as upvote arrows on this page.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a close-quote after `"class`:

```
 maxx = soup.findAll("href", {"class: "yil-biz-ttl"})
```

should be

```
 maxx = soup.findAll("href", {"class": "yil-biz-ttl"})
```

also, I don't think you can search for an attribute like `href` like that, I think you need to search for a tag:

```
 maxx = [link['href'] for link in soup.findAll("a", {"class": "yil-biz-ttl"})]
```

Comment: You should also filter `<a/>` elements that don't have `href` attribute.

Comment: `link['href'] might be more appropriate than `link.href` here. The latter returns the first child `<href/>` element of the link (not its attribute).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I've edited to the key version. I though I saw that syntax right in the beautiful soup documentation, but looking at it now it seems it's just for `tag.name` which I guess is special?

Comment: This still breaks on `<a>` elements without `href` attribute

Comment: Yes, I saw the comment you added to _every answer_. I upvoted it on mine as it's useful info. However, the OP only has to worry about that if the page they're parsing has anchors without hrefs.

Answer (score 3):

To find all `<a/>` elements from CSS class `"yil-biz-ttl"` that have `href` attribute with anything in it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML)
for link in soup("a", "yil-biz-ttl", href=True):
    print(link['href'])
```

At the moment all other answers don't satisfy the above requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you have a syntax error. You have your quotes wrong in `class` part.

Try:

`maxx = soup.findAll("href", {"class": "yil-biz-ttl"})`

Comment: The example html from the question shows that the OP cares about `<a/>` elements, not `<href/>`